# return type in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

int & fun();
int main()
{
    int p = fun();
    std::cout << p;
    return 0;
}

int & fun()
{
    int a=10;
    return a;
}
```

Why is this program not giving error at line no.6 as "invalid conversion from int* to int", as it happens in case we do like this?

```
 int x = 9;
 int a = &x;
```

Comment: In `int a = &x;`, the `&` means "address of", which returns a pointer. You are trying to assign a pointer to `x` to an integer, which is illegal.

Comment: I think you only know C. C++ is different from C. int & means reference but not address operator. & has multiple meanings in C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the ampersand for when used after class name like ostream& operator <<(...)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1572016/90527)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int&` is a type; it means "a reference to `int`."

`&x` is an expression; it means "take the address of `x`."  The unary `&` operator is the address operator.  It takes the address of its argument.  If `x` is an `int`, then the type of `&x` is "a pointer to `int`" (that is, `int*`).

`int&` and `int*` are different types.  References and pointers are the same in many respects; namely, they both refer to objects, but they are quite different in how they are used.  For one thing, a reference implicitly refers to an object and no indirection is needed to get to the referenced object.  Explicit indirection (using `*` or `->`) is needed to get the object referenced by a pointer.

These two uses of the `&` are completely different.  They aren't the only uses either:  for example, there is also the binary `&` operator that performs the bitwise and operation.

---

Note also that your function `fun` is incorrect because you return a reference to a local variable.  Once the function returns, `a` is destroyed and ceases to exist so you can never use the reference that is returned from the function.  If you do use it, e.g. by assigning the result of `fun()` to `p` as you do, the behavior is undefined.

When returning a reference from a function you must be certain that the object to which the reference refers will exist after the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this program not giving error at line no.5 as "invalid conversion from int* to int", as it happens in case we do like this?

That's because you are trying to return the variable by reference and not by address. However your code invokes Undefined Behaviour because returning a reference to a local variable and then using the result is UB.

Answer (score 1):

Because in one case its a pointer and in the other a reference:

int a=&x means set a to the address of x - wrong

int &p=fun() means set p to a reference to an int - ok

Answer (score 0):

Functions in C++ are not same as macros i.e. when you qrite `int p = fun()` it doesn't become `int p = &a;` (I guess that is what you are expecting from your question). What you are doing is returning a *reference* from the function `f`. You are no where taking address of any variable. BTW, the above code will invoke undfeined behavior as you are returning a reference to the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning an `int *`, you're retuning an `int &`. That is, you're returning a reference to an integer, not a pointer. That reference can decay into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different things, although they both use the ampersand symbol.  In your first example, you are returning a *reference* to an int, which is assignable to an int.  In your second example, you are trying to assign the *address* of x (pointer) to an int, which is illegal.