# Problem with temporaries

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [return type in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932239/return-type-in-c)

```
#include<iostream>
int& fun();
int main()
{
  int p=fun();
  std::cout<<p;
  return 0;
}

int & fun()
{
  int a=10;
  return  &a;
}
```

why does this code give error as,error: `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int*'`..Actually i am not clear about the temporaries i.e. when are they created and when are they get destroyed.?so ,please explain temporaries to some extent  too.

Comment: What happens in your code doesn't change. `&a` is a pointer, and `int&` is a reference, they are not compatible. Also, you're returning a **dangling** pointer/reference. But all of that was already explained in your other question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&a` generates a temporary which cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

Moreover your code has several flaws.

1) `&a` has type `int*` whereas you are returning by reference i.e `int &`. The types don't match.

2) Even if you change `&a` to `a` in the return statement you code still won't work because returning a local variable by reference and then **using** the result is UB.

---

**Invalid initialization of non-const reference from a temporary**

C++ doesn't allow temporaries to be bound to non constant references.

For example you can't do something like this

```
int &x = 5;
```

because the temporary `int(5)` would be destroyed at the end the expression which it is a part of. However references to const can be initialized from a temporary i.e you can safely write

`const int &x = 5;`

In this case attaching the temporary to a const-reference prolongs its lifetime. It gets destroyed when `x` gets destroyed.

Comment: +1 For good explanation, as you always do :)

Comment: What this sentence is supposed to mean : "*&a generates a temporary which cannot be bound to a non-const reference.*"

Comment: @Nawaz : The return type is a reference to non const. `&a` generates a temporary to be bound to the return value of the function (`int&` is the type) but C++ doesn't allow temporaries to be attached to non-const references and that's why gcc gives such error.

Comment: The return type is a reference to non-const **what**?

Comment: `&a` yields a pointer, not a temporary. There is no expression in C++ that yields a scalar temporary, you only get them by binding scalar rvalues to lvalue-references-to-const or rvalue-references.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream> 

int& fun(); 
int main() 
{   
    int p=fun();  
    std::cout<<p;  
    return 0; 
}  

int & fun() 
{   
   int a=10;   
   return  a; //Return a not &a
}
```

The error `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int*'' is because you are returning`&a`and not`a`.
Above code would compile correctly but it has a serious flaw. 
It returns a reference to a temporary stack variable in the function, Once the function returns all the stack variables get destroyed because of stack unwinding, Eventually you are left pointing to a address location that does not contain valid or values you expected.

***You should always avoid returning pointers of references to local objects on stack!***

The correct way to do this will be:

```
#include<iostream> 

int* fun(); 
int main() 
{   
    int *p =fun();  
    std::cout<< *p;  
    delete p; //delete dynamically allocated memory else memory leak
    return 0; 
}  

int* fun() 
{   
   int *a = new int;  //allocate dynamic memory 
   *a = 10;
   return  a; 
}
```

Comment: This is ill-defined and results in indeterministic behavior. Compilers should give you a "returning reference to a local variable" warning here.

Comment: @Nathan Ernst, @Prasoon Saurav: I am explaning the OP why the specific error and I am still editing it..Patience!

Comment: sorry, SO doesn't show edit's are in progress. ;)

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav, @Nathan Ernst: It's ok...Ahh...trying to live around with my slow desktop is such a pain! :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to return `&a` from `fun` because `a` was allocated on the stack, and is not guaranteed to retain its value after `fun` returns.

You will need to use `new` or `malloc` to obtain heap-allocated memory (and then `delete` or `free` it afterwards) if you want the values to persist after `fun` returns. All variables normally declared in a function (for example as `int foo`) reside in its stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable a is allocated on the stack and will go away as soon as the function returns leaving you with a reference to a bogus address.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `&a` means "address of `a`."  So you're not actually returning an `int` reference there; you're returning a pointer.

In either case, you should allocate `a` with `new` and then `delete` it later, or you'll run into undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of your function is `int&`. The expression in `foo` of `&a` (address-of) has type `int*`. To get a type of `int&`, you'd have to use the expression `*&a`. What this does is take the address of `a` and then dereference it, resulting in a reference, instead of a pointer. NOTE: Returning a reference (or pointer) to a non-static local-variable is ill-defined and will result in undefined behavior (best case: you can't reliably count on the value. worst-case: your hard-drive is reformatted).

In this case, you basically have 2 options: change the signature of your function to `int foo()`, or change the declaration of the local in `a` to be `static int a` and the return statement to just `return a;`. Note that changing `a` to be a static will make the function non-rentrant and non-threadsafe.